# react-native get release build package name / bundle id during build?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using firebase for my app and have 2 iOS targets and 2 android flavours, lets call them `production` and `development`. These use different firebase projects and are built in ci as release builds.

Here comes the issue, I need to provide different configuration to certain firebase calls where I need to pass bunlde ids / package ids (from javascript code).

As I am always in release mode when building these, I can't rely on global DEV variable.

Is there a way for me to find out what target / flavour is being build inside js code and adjust stuff there based on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access that information through buildConfigField fields for android and environment.plist settings for iOS.

The you can use the frameworks react-native-build-config and react-native-userdefaults-ios to access they in your js code.

So on android you would set a buildConfigField in you productFlavor in your app/build.gradle file:

```
buildConfigField "String", "CONFIGURATION_VARIABLE", '"some_url_or_other_info"'
```

and then access it through react-native-build-config in js.

On iOS you just create 2 environment.plist files, with names like environment_production.plist and environment_development.plist. The under Build Phases -> Setup Environment you can add a script to choose between them: (In the example i do the same thing for the GoogleServices-info file which is also different for me)

```
    if [ ${CONFIGURATION} == "Production" ]
then
    cp ${PROJECT_DIR}/environment_production.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/environment.plist
    cp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.production.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist

else
    cp ${PROJECT_DIR}/environment_development.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/environment.plist
    cp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.development.plist ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist
fi
```

It will then be visible in userDefaults from js. 
Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I think installing two packages to achieve this is a bit of an overkill however. There are alternatives like `react-native-device-info` and `react-native-config` that enable same thing. I am interested if there is more "vanilla" react-native approach for this